# How to interpret correctly this chart about nitrogen oxide?

Tags: self-study, data-visualization

I found the below chart in a test for university access in Sweden, with the following question:

How large was the total emission of nitrogen oxides caused by Swedish consumption under the period 2004-2008?

I have the correct solution, but it does not match my answer. I reasoned like this:

- Both 2004 and 2008 should be included, so we have 5 years.
- The emissions abroad are about 112 thousand tons on average, so 112*5 = 560
- The emissions in Sweden are about 225 thousand tons on average, so 225*5 = 1100.
- So the total should be about 160+1100 = 1660.

However, apparently the correct answer is 1100.

I am quite sure I am missing something obvious, but I cannot figure it out.

Translation of the most important terms:

Utsläpp i Sverige: emission in Sweden
Utsläpp utomlands: emission abroad (caused by imports).

[image]

The original question in Swedish:

> Hur stort var det sammanlagda utsläppet av kväveoxider orsakat av svensk konsumtion under perioden 2004-2008?

Comment: This is a great example of an awful exam question.  The chart is inconsistent: its graphical construction (including drawing continuous lines for the annual values) implies the vertical axis represents a quantity *per unit time* rather than a total quantity.  The title therefore is inaccurate; it ought to read something like "Tons of NOx per year." As your reasoning indicates, the legend is incorrect, too.  The question itself remains ambiguous concerning whether the time period spans four or five years.

Comment: It's nice to see that somebody agrees that it was ambiguous. How would you call this type of chart?

Comment: One pithy description would be it's a mis-drawn version of a stacked bar chart.  From an alternative viewpoint, it's a mis-application of a stacked area chart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A person answered to me on a [dedicated Facebook group](https://www.facebook.com/groups/468485986570404/permalink/2647172855368362/?comment_id=2647181812034133). He suggests that the labels are about areas, not lines, so the grey area (emissions in Sweden), is only the visible area, it does not continue below the dark area (emissions abroad). I find this representation very confusing.

[Sal Mangiafico](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/166526/sal-mangiafico) in a comment refers to this as a "Stacked area chart".

As an example, the emissions in Sweden in 2008 are 225 - 100 = 125, the difference between the total and the dark area, and not 100 as I thought.

This way, the correct answer is 1100, because the upper line already represents the total emissions, and between 2004 and 2008 we have an average of 225 for 5 years.

Comment: Yes, I think that's the natural interpretation of the plot.  The values are "stacked".  "Stacked area chart".